# boost::filesystem::unique_path returns empty string on android

Tags: android, boost-filesystem

On android, this:

```
std::string path = boost::filesystem::unique_path().string();
```

returns the empty string. No exception or other error condition that I can detect. Specifically this is a Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.2. Any idea what's up here?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.  There is something wrong in the conversion function when returning a wstring to construct a path object.  Our workaround for now is to use boost::nowide to return a std::string in unique_path.cpp.